# Enable SP-Feature is unavailable

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, sharepoint

I'm trying to use Powershell to enable the devlopment feature on a SharePoint site (as per this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx) When I do this I'm presented with the following error:

> The term 'Enable-SPFeature' is not recognized' as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

A screenshot of my input/output is below:

[image]

I'm unsure why this is happening - I'm on the SharePoint server I want to enable this feature on and as far as  I know everything required is installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone going forward, however when I added the Snapin it still failed.  I needed to also explicitly Import the module too like so:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Import-Module ‘C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell’ -DisableNameChecking
```

I had downloaded the Snapin from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding the SharePoint snap-in to your current session?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

Comment: Ahem. Whoops! That's embarrassing...

Comment: We have all been there.

Comment: @darinstrait I've tried running this after installing SharePoint PowerShell, but I get "snap-in 'Microsofot.SharePoint.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer. Is this something else that needs to be installed separately?

Comment: @darinstrait this is for Sharepoint Online by the way. Not sure if that makes a difference. I've installed SharePoint Online Management Shell from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=35588